# Enable sort for wpf DataGridColumn which source is converted value

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, converters

In my wpf/c# project I have datatype with 3 dimensions: length, width and depth. When user inputs those in datagrid the volume for this item is calculated in 4th column using converter. What I want is **to enable sort for this column**. I tried to put SortMemberPath to Converter return value, but this did not worked. I think one way to do this is to extend my datatype with one more property, but I would like to avoid this if it is possible, using only some xaml/converters technique.

Datatype definition:

```
public partial class packs
{        
    public packs()
    {
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public Nullable<decimal> length { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> width { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> depth { get; set; }      
}
```

ViewModel

```
public PacksVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<packs> Packs{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

View

```
...
<DataGrid 
          x:Name="furniturePackagesGrid"                                                       
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Packs}"
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>                                                 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" 
            Binding="{Binding length}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" 
            Binding="{Binding width}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Depth" 
            Binding="{Binding depth}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Volume (m3)"  
            Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PackVolumeConverter}}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserSort="True"
<!--I show no code for PackVolumeSortConverter because it is never called-->
            SortMemberPath="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PackVolumeSortConverter}}"
             />                                                          
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

and VolumeConverter

```
public class PackVolumeConverter : IValueConverter
{   
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var package = value as packs;
        decimal volume = 0;
        if(package != null)
        {
            volume = (package.length ?? default(decimal)) *
                     (package.width ?? default(decimal)) * 
                     (package.depth ?? default(decimal)) / 1000000000;

                return volume;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type TargetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read in the documentation the `SortMemberPath` is not bindable in the sense you do but should contain a string with the path to the property to sort by.

If you don't want to polute the `packs class` with a volume property the only way I can come up with is to make a view model wrapper for that class:

```
  public class VMPacks
  {
    public VMPacks(packs p)
    {
      Packs = p;
    }

    public packs Packs { get; private set; }

    public decimal Volume
    {
      get
      {
        decimal volume = (Packs.length ?? default(decimal)) *
                 (Packs.width ?? default(decimal)) *
                 (Packs.depth ?? default(decimal)) / 1000000000;

        return volume;
      }
    }

  }
```

and then adjust your column bindings accordingly or alternatively make proper Properties and possible implement INotifyPropertyChanged etc.

---

**EDIT:**

It is infact possible to do a custom sort in the following way:

Add a Sorting event handler to the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid 
  x:Name="furniturePackagesGrid"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  Sorting="furniturePackagesGrid_Sorting"
  >
```

Set the SortMemberPath to a dummy value like:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Volume (m3)"                            
                        Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PackVolumeConverter}}"
                        IsReadOnly="True"      
                        SortMemberPath="depth"
                        CanUserSort="True" />
```

This is just to avoid a binding expression error.

Finally implement the Sorting event handler like this:

```
private void furniturePackagesGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Column.DisplayIndex == 3)
  {
    DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;

    List<packs> packs = grid.ItemsSource as List<packs>;

    Func<packs, decimal> volume = (p) =>
    {
      decimal v = (p.length ?? default(decimal)) *
        (p.width ?? default(decimal)) *
        (p.depth ?? default(decimal)) / 1000000000;
      return v;
    };

    packs.Sort((p1, p2) =>
    {
      if (p1 == p2)
        return 0;

      if (e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending)
        return Decimal.Compare(volume(p2), volume(p1));
      return Decimal.Compare(volume(p1), volume(p2));
    });

    grid.ItemsSource = packs;
  }
}
```

It requires that the DataGrid.ItemsSource is populated as a List:

```
  furniturePackagesGrid.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => new packs
  {
    depth = 2 + i,
    id = i,
    length = 3 + i,
    width = 4 + i,
  }).ToList();
```